# Should I use a full stop at the end of text in a table?

Tags: punctuation, periods

The table has a mix of fragments and full sentences. I'm concerned that if I have full stops after the sentences and none after the fragments it will look inconsistent to the reader.

Comment: can you please provide a little more information about the content?

Comment: Examples, and the purpose of the table, would certainly help.

Comment: These are some of the entries from the table: 'Gas cleaning may be required.' (sentence) 'Most expensive to install' (fragment) 'Energy offsets to reduce production costs' (fragment) 'Cost of covering ponds may be prohibitive.' (sentence).

Comment: Why not leave the full stop off all of them?

Comment: Thank you. I had thought of this option but am concerned about having sentences without full stops. Thought there may be some advice in a style manual about the conventions for this in tables.

Comment: Where there is a sentence, there ought to be a period at its end, or it will not be a sentence. If you do not want to distinguish between the table elements and treat all of them as phrases, rather than sentences and phrases, you don't need a period. Else you must use a period at the end of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts are correct.

In bulleted lists, as in tables and spreadsheets, the word is consistency. Unfortunately, there is no hard and fast rule - it is a stylistic choice.

That said, most writers do not put full stops at the end of each list item unless each and every item is a full sentence. Even if they are full sentences, some style manuals dictate no full stops anyway.

As yours are not all full sentences, leave out the full stops on all items.

Answer (score 0):

The actual content and design you are seeking will be the deciding most factor in implementing a solution. However, you may consider:

1. Using a semicolon. This maintains the connection between the clauses while ensuring a pause between the two ideas. E.g:

   > It is nearly half past five; we cannot reach town before dark.
2. Using a coordinating conjunction with a comma. E.g:

   > It is nearly half past five, so we cannot reach town before dark.

Comment: @Melinda,
[bold]Gas cleaning may be required.[bold].[line break] Most expensive to install | Energy offsets to reduce production costs | Cost of covering ponds may be prohibitive.

Comment: Thanks Raghav but the second and third are still fragments (use non-finite verbs). I opted for no stops on all behind cover of 'special use in tables'.

Answer (score -1):

Consistency is the important thing.
After that it is a matter of choice.
All full stops or no full stops at all, even after full sentences.
Eli Sluszny

Comment: I don't think omitting a full stop after a full sentence is a good option, no matter how consistent.

Comment: Welcome to ELU :-). This is primarily an opinion-based post and it is more suited to be a comment than an answer. It is desirable to include [references](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in your answer, whenever that is possible.